# 502 Bad Gateway nginx 1.20.1

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, deployment, gateway

I know why is this coming.
But I don't know how to fix it.
I was installing osticket following this article.
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-osticket-on-centos-7/
Turns out current osticket requires php 8.0+.
Then I remove php 7.4 using

```
yum -y remove php*
```

Now, I installed php 8.x+ using this

```
# yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
# yum install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
# yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php80 php php-cli
```

Now I'm getting 502 bad gateway when I open the server.

I looked around and thought that this was proably due to  me not using this command.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable php-fpm.service
```

So, I tried to do this but it failed saying.

```
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

I got disappointed. How do I fix this issue?

```
2023/09/12 14:06:58 [error] 993#993: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.13.165.134, server: example.com, request: "GET /setup/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "10.13.165.100"
```

This is what my nginx error.log says.

Comment: For proper repository configuration and usage, follow the wizard https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/
And of course you need to install the FPM service.

Comment: Also, notice that EL-7 is terribly old, and close to its EOL in a few months.
I recommend using a more recent EL-8 or EL-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the commands you provided above, you did not install php-fpm. You need to run

```
yum install --enablerepo=remi-php80 php-fpm
```